# Launching an android activity via a class name

Tags: android

How can I launch an android activity via a specified class name of an activity?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your base Activity (say, via an option menu click):

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
Intent intent = new Intent (this, NewActivity.class);
startActivityForResult (intent, SOME_ACTIVITY_ID);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Don't forget to add the activity class name to the manifest file.